# Joining a second table and selecting the first entry

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been having some troubles getting my head around achieving the below.

I have an 'applications' table and a 'application_logs' table. I am attempting to select all the applications where the 'type' is equal to 'test' and then join the 'application_logs' table and retrieve only the first log entry for the application.

One of the queries I tried and understood most was: (whilst this didn't fail it looked like an endless loop and completed the query.

```
SELECT applications.id FROM applications JOIN application_logs ON application_logs.application_id =
(
    SELECT application_logs.id FROM application_logs
    WHERE application_logs.application_id = applications.id
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 1
)
WHERE type = 'test';
```

There were some other queries (using CROSS APPLY/distinct) I attempted but they didn't make sense to me and didn't look like they were trying to achieve the same thing. I appreciate all the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
SELECT a.id, ay.*
FROM applications AS a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT al.application_id, min(al.id) as Min_Id
    FROM application_logs AS al
    GROUP BY al.application_id
) AS ax ON ax.application_id = a.id
INNER JOIN application_logs AS ay ON ay.id = ax.id
WHERE a.type = 'test';
```

Comment: I get "Unknown column 'applications.id' in 'field list'

Comment: @user3724476: That's a mere typo. The `applications` table is alieased with `a`, so use `a.id` instead of `applications.id` in the select clause. (This is something you should have noticed by yourself by the way. Have you studied this query and understood it?)

Comment: @Thorsten_Kettner, Thank you for explanation. :) I have corrected typo.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this in standard SQL. A lateral join (`CROSS APPLY`) is the first to come to mind, but MySQL doesn't support it. Another would be `FETCH FIRST ROWS WITH TIES` to get all latest application logs, but MySQL doesn't support it (and its counterpart `LIMIT` doesn't have a ties clause either). If you are only interested in the application ID alone (as shown in your query) one could even combine this with an `INTERSECT` operation, but MySQL doesn't support it.

After all you want to find out the maximum log ID per application ID. As of MySQL 8 you can do this on-the-fly:

```
select *
from applications a
left join
(
  select
    application_logs.*,
    max(id) over (partition by application_id) as max_application_id
  from application_logs
) al on al.application_id = a.id and al.application_id = al.max_application_id
where a.type = 'test';
```

In earlier vesions you would do this in separate steps. One way would be this:

```
select *
from applications a
left join application_logs al
  on al.application_id = alm.application_id
  and (al.application_id, al.id) in
  (
    select application_id, max(id)
    from application_logs
    group by application_id
  )
where a.type = 'test';
```

Another is your own query, where you only got confused with the IDs:

```
SELECT *
FROM applications a
JOIN application_logs al ON al.id =
(
  SELECT almax.id
  FROM application_logs almax
  WHERE almax.application_id = a.id
  ORDER BY almax.id DESC
  LIMIT 1
)
WHERE a.type = 'test';
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT
    a.*, c.*
FROM
    applications a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        al.application_id AS application_id,
        MAX(al.id) AS al_id
    FROM
        application_logs al
    GROUP BY
        al.application_id
) c ON a.id = c.application_id
WHERE
    a.type = 'test';
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the first entry from application_logs table with respect to application_id. You need to use Row_Number Over (partition by order by ).

```
SELECT      *
FROM        applications   A
LEFT        JOIN    (
                SELECT  Id AS applications.id 
                FROM (
                    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition By applications.id ORDER BY application_logs.id) as R, application_logs.id, applications.id
                    FROM    application_logs
                ) AS S
                WHERE R = 1
            ) AS L ON L.applications.id = A.applications.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query suggests that "first" means the largest `id`.  (Colloquially, I would expect "first" to mean the smallest `id` or earliest chronologically.)

I usually recommend a correlated subquery for the filtering.  It is worth testing if this is faster than other methods:

```
select . . .
from applications a join
     application_logs al
     on al.application_id = a.id
where a.type = 'test' and
      al.id = (select max(al2.id)
               from application_logs al2
               where al2.application_id = al.application_id
              );
```

The optimal indexes for performance are:

- `application(type, id)`
- `application_logs(application_id, id)`

Comment: I guess you mean `Type` in first index instead of `Test`.